# Determining if observations from a sample are equally distributed among three categories

Tags: chi-squared-test, multiple-comparisons, proportion

My data is composed of 301 observations from 34 subjects, each subject can have one or more observations (up to 15).
Each observation belong to one of three categories.
Two of the categories differ only slightly.

Think of the three categories as an attribute.
E.g. type of vehicle:

```
CAT1 = four wheels car
CAT2 = four wheels truck
CAT3 = two wheels 


data
------------
 obs   CAT
------------
  1     1
  2     3
  3     2
  4     1
  5     1
  6     3
  .     .  
  .     .
  .     .


summary
-------------
CAT1: 133 obs
CAT2: 114 obs
CAT3: 54 obs
```

Question 1:
How can I test whether the 301 observations are equally distributed among the three categories or not? 
Can I can use Chi-squared even if I have only one variable (category)?

Question 2:
Which test is robust to the bias of having two categories being only slightly different?
I fear that the way the categories have been devised might render the comparison unfair (E.g. throwing rocks in three circles, where two of the circles are substantially the same).